# In WPF how do I access a WrapPanel from CodeBehind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, runtime-error

I have a WrapPanel defined as follows in XAML...

```
<Page x:Class="SelectImages"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="320" d:DesignWidth="480"
      Title="Select Images">
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel Name="MyImagePanel" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="10,50,10,10"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </WrapPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

When I try to use the WrapPanel as below in my Code Behind I get a runtime error "Object reference not set to instance of object".

```
Private Sub AddImageToPanel(Image As FileSystemInfo)
    MyImagePanel.Children.Add(NewPicture(Image))
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: `MyImagePanel`will be `null` until after `InitializeComponent()` has been called. And `Image As FileSystemInfo` might be `null` in case `Image` is `null` or not a `FileSystemInfo`. Find out what exactly is `null`. Or post the exception stack.

Comment: Have a look to the call stack to see where is the null exception.

Comment: `MyImagePanel` is null.  And I've also tested other controls on the same page.  All of them are returning the same error and all controls are null at runtime even though they are declared in the XAML.

Comment: Could you give us a little more on your code-behind, there must be something wrong somewhere there, they shouldn't be null.

Comment: How are you calling AddImageToPanel btw ?

Comment: I think I got it... I was navigating to this page using ...

    `Dim SelectImagesPage As New SelectImages(FolderPath, SelectedProductID)` _ `Me.NavigationService.Navigate(SelectImagesPage)`

Seems the constructor doesn't automatically initialise the components.  Added `InitializeComponent()` to the constructor on my page and now it all works.

Comment: Confirmed. This book (http://books.google.fr/books?id=_6j1qH9hSs0C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), p30, says the default constructor hide the call to InitializeComponent, but that you should add the call yourself in custom constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was navigating to this page using ...

`Dim SelectImagesPage As New SelectImages(FolderPath, SelectedProductID)
Me.NavigationService.Navigate(SelectImagesPage)`

Seems the constructor doesn't automatically initialise the components. Added `InitializeComponent()` to the constructor on my page and now it all works.